# Hypothetical sample size

Tags: r, sample-size, resampling

I have a data set of n=98 of values that is normal distributed. This data set has a certain spread and hence a certain standard error of the mean. I now want to test how many samples (ns) I would need to reduce the SEM to a certain value. Could this be done by resampling and if so how would this be done?

Comment: Because the SEM is proportional to $1/\sqrt{n},$ you can solve this problem in your head: no simulation is needed.  You have to assume, of course, that the additional sample will exhibit the same standard deviation as the original sample.  So: is it essential that we respond to the part of the question about simulation?

Comment: Yes you are completely right. How did I miss that? Thank you very much!